# JWPlayer onNext and onPrevious events?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Does JWPlayer have onNext or onPrevious events for a playlist? I wasn't able to find anything.

What I need to happen is that the URL hash is updated when someone clicks previous or next in the JWplayer

Comment: We do not have events for these, I'm afraid.

Comment: Meh, too bad. Guess I'll have to have a look at the implementation again. Thanks for the answer

Comment: oh btw, do you know if there is a different way to know what triggered a onPlaylistItem?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. onPlaylistItem is the only way?

Comment: Got a solution already :) Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Cool, np :) How did you end up solving?

Comment: First I was trying to control the playlist with the name of the video. Now I'm controlling it purely with the playlistitem index. With the playlistitem index I can get the playing item and update the rest of the page (titles, description etc.) Only on a fresh pageload should I take the name into account to select the right item in the pagelist. I do this by running some code on pageload after the player init. It's kind of tricky but it works.

Comment: Ah, very nice, thanks for sharing =)